# Pre-selection states and pre-requisite choices

Tags: interaction-design, users, ux-designer

I'm trying to create a selection which has a pre-requisite state that must be selected, before you can select additional checks within that check.

So unless a user selects an 'Enhanced Check' they cannot select the child or adult options.

If they select an 'Enhanced Check' then they can select 'Adult' or 'Child' or both.

This selection has an importance factor/weighting to it, hence the colour scheme, but that is affecting the disabled/on/off states of the check buttons. Here's what I have so far:

[image: Default State]

[image: Enhanced Selected]

[image: All Selected]

Could this control be improved to make the choices more obvious and ensure the user experience isn't confused? At this moment in time it's not working for me.

**UPDATE**

Well you can't count for stakeholders, they didn't like the design at all, it's not 'government' enough, I've updated the solution with my own answer to show the active and inactive states.

Comment: Does your current implementation allow for the hiding of elements under "Enhanced Check"?

Comment: Possibly, I'd avoided hiding them as the people using this interface generally won't be experts. They will use a guide that tells them what check they need and then they'll return to this site to select the appropriate one. If the choice is hidden it may confuse them from what they've read in the guide, if they can't see the option.

Comment: Understood. However, I'm confused: is the enhanced check a binding agreement? Why wouldn't selecting Child or Adult automatically indicate the Enhanced Check meaning? Seems like an unnecessary step if it's not a branching or binding type of selection.

Comment: You're right in that respect, if you were checking the barred lists, you would be having an enhanced check, but again, loath to hide enhanced as you can have an enhanced check without the barred check.

Answer (score 3):

[image: Default State]

[image: Enhanced Selected]

[image: Standard Selected]

I agree with them [stakeholders] that it's simpler and provides more contrast.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding some contrast in the text to differentiate titles and labels. Something like this would help avoid confusion -

[image]

Comment: This looks better than my suggestion, will mock-up and test, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

#### Try separating the status from the preferences (the affected items).

What about a toggle (or radio button) that indicates an enabled / disabled state, rather than a checkbox?

Try treating the **enhanced check** as a separate type of control (it's really a feature you can turn on and off), and then you can preserve preferences at the list level, rather than burden the user with having to remember the barred list preferences.

That way users could keep their choice of barred lists (especially if the lists get long), but turn 'on / off' the enhanced check feature:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkIhp4.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>